# How do I set WINS server for OpenVPN running on pfSense?

Tags: openvpn, pfsense, wins

I have a OpenVPN Server running on pfSense 2.0.3. I can't find an option to add WINS address for VPN connections. I tried going to VPN > OpenVPN > Server > Edit server > Client Settings > NetBIOS Options and enabling it. However I must have configured it wrong because of multiple restarts I still can't access computers via name (\SERVER).

How do I set WINS server for VPN clients?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used pfSense, but I can tell you that you're looking for the `push "dhcp-option WINS x.x.x.x` configuration directive for OpenVPN. There's an "Advanced Configuration" tab, apparently, where you can enter this stuff in the GUI. Give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The option to "Provide a WINS server list to clients" in the GUI sets the "dhcp-option WINS ..." accordingly in OpenVPN.